# Query is too slow, how can I optimize it?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a lot of data and I have problem with query optimization.
How can I optimize this query

```
explain SELECT distinct UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)*1000 as timestamp,count(ip_src) as counter from acid_event a,saher.network n where inet_aton(n.net)!=a.ip_src group by timestamp;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------   +------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | n     | index | NULL          | fsi         | 27      | NULL | 2691027 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | index | NULL          | timestamp_2 | 13      | NULL | 6770718 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer  |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to get rid of `INET_ATON()` by e.g. adding a new column with the numeric value of the IP address to your `acid_event` table
2. then, if the result set is big (e.g. many thousands), get rid of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)*1000`
3. if this is not enough, fix the indexes. Here's a [book](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) that explains indexes in depth.

Comment: 4. Don't mix GROUP BY and DISTINCT.

Comment: 5. You are JOINing two tables in a very strange way (using != instead of =).